# Convert TIF file to CSV/ASCII format using QGIS v. 3.24.1-Tisler

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, dem, convert, csv

I have DTM data in the format of .tif and I need to export this as CSV or ASC for point cloud data input into Leapfrog.

I've read other walk-thrus that are outdated now (2014/2017) that came close to the solution, but sadly QGIS has been updated since that time and I need a current solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you export the raster file to XYZ format in QGIS, it is in fact the CSV (ASCII Gridded - see: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html) - each line contains X, Y and the Z value separated by space (or comma if you want). Right click on the raster item in list of layers, choose Export, Save as...
Alternatively [MyGeodata Converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/) can export it to XYZ online.

Comment: Or menu Raster -> Conversion -> Translate -> Save to file -> XYZ

Comment: Tried this... not an option on current QGIS version.  Thanks.  The answer below wins it! "Processing Toolbox", woot!

Answer (score 0):

In the Processing Toolbox, GDAL >> gdal2xyz.
[image]

Comment: You win!  This is the solution!  Thanks so much!

Comment: However, the gdal2xyz did not write the Z values in the exported csv file, just a bunch of -10000 values.  Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: What was the elevation range when you drag-n-dropped the tif into QGIS?